# `staticmethod` and `abc.abstractmethod`: Will it blend?

Tags: python, abstract-class, static-methods, python-decorators, abstract-methods

In my Python app I want to make a method that is both a `staticmethod` and an [`abc.abstractmethod`](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod). How do I do this?

I tried applying both decorators, but it doesn't work. If I do this:

```py
import abc

class C(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @abc.abstractmethod
    @staticmethod    
    def my_function(): pass
```

I get an exception*, and if I do this:

```py
class C(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta

    @staticmethod    
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def my_function(): pass
```

The abstract method is not enforced.

How can I make an abstract static method?

*The exception:

```
File "c:\Python26\Lib\abc.py", line 29, in abstractmethod
 funcobj.__isabstractmethod__ = True
AttributeError: 'staticmethod' object has no attribute '__isabstractmethod__'
```

Answer (score 386, accepted):

Starting with **Python 3.3**, it is [possible to combine](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) `@staticmethod` and `@abstractmethod`, so none of the other suggestions are necessary anymore:

```
@staticmethod
@abstractmethod
def my_abstract_staticmethod(...):
```

Further `@abstractstatic` is deprecated since [version 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractstaticmethod).

Comment: Note that you have to put `@staticmethod` as first, or you'll get `AttributeError: attribute '__isabstractmethod__' of 'staticmethod' objects is not writable`

Comment: Same for `@property`

Comment: Deprecated in 3.3, but still there in 3.10   :-)

Answer (score 41):

```
class abstractstatic(staticmethod):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, function):
        super(abstractstatic, self).__init__(function)
        function.__isabstractmethod__ = True
    __isabstractmethod__ = True

class A(object):
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abstractstatic
    def test():
        print 5
```

Comment: Well played, sir or madam :-) You left out `import abc` at the top; as well as a subclass that shows instantiation of A. (e.g., `class B(A):\n @staticmethod\n def test():\n print 10\n`)

Comment: I updated the code to work properly with subclassing. A.test should also have the `__isabstractmethod__` attribute.

Comment: Should `abstractstatic` be added upstream to `abc.py`?

Comment: abstractstaticmethod Deprecated since version 3.3: It is now possible to use staticmethod with abstractmethod(), making this decorator redundant. [link](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractstaticmethod)

Comment: @iraklikhitarishvili Still, that doesn't enforce the subclass's method to be static! You have to duplicate the staticmethod decorator... Is there no way around that?

Comment: @DiegoAlonsoCortez Sorry for late answer. I prefer writing ``@staticmethod`` to each implementation. but if you want you can create subclass of ``ABCMeta`` and override ``__new__`` method to check if the base class's method is static and if is then make child's method static too.[example](http://pastebin.com/DNmjtfdQ). but i don't like this approach. –

Comment: Sorry had to -1 for not adding any explanation

Answer (score 16):

This will do it:

```
  >>> import abc
  >>> abstractstaticmethod = abc.abstractmethod
  >>>
  >>> class A(object):
  ...     __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
  ...     @abstractstaticmethod
  ...     def themethod():
  ...          pass
  ... 
  >>> a = A()
  >>> Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "asm.py", line 16, in <module>
    a = A()
  TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class A with abstract methods test
```

You go "Eh? It just renames @abstractmethod", and this is completely correct. Because any subclass of the above will have to include the @staticmethod decorator anyway. You have no need of it here, except as documentation when reading the code. A subclass would have to look like this:

```
  >>> class B(A):
  ...     @staticmethod
  ...     def themethod():
  ...         print "Do whatevs"
```

To have a function that would enforce you to make this method a static method you would have to subclass ABCmeta to check for that and enforce it. That's a lot of work for no real return. (If somebody forgets the @staticmethod decorator they will get a clear error anyway, it just won't mention static methods.

So in fact this works just as well:

```
  >>> import abc
  >>>
  >>> class A(object):
  ...     __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
  ...     @abc.abstractmethod
  ...     def themethod():
  ...         """Subclasses must implement this as a @staticmethod"""
  ...          pass
```

Update - Another way to explain it:

That a method is static controls how it is called.
An abstract method is never called.
And abstract static method is therefore a pretty pointless concept, except for documentation purposes.

Answer (score 6):

This is currently not possible in Python 2.X, which will only enforce the method to be abstract or static, but not both.

In Python 3.2+, the new decorators`abc.abstractclassmethod` and `abc.abstractstaticmethod` were added to combine their enforcement of being abstract and static or abstract and a class method.

See [Python Issue 5867](http://bugs.python.org/issue5867)

Comment: While new in Python 3.2, `abstractclassmethod` and `abstractstaticmethod` were rapidly deprecated in Python 3.3, as well as `abstractproperty`. http://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html

Comment: FYI: http://bugs.python.org/issue11610  describes the deprication, and new way to do it...

Answer (score 1):

[The documentation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes/74534218#74534218) says below:

> When `abstractmethod()` is applied in combination with other method
> descriptors, it should be applied as the innermost decorator, ...

So, `@abstractmethod` must be **the innermost decorator** as shown below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Person(ABC):

    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def test1(cls):
        pass
    
    @staticmethod
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def test2():
        pass

    @property
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self):
        pass

    @name.setter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self, name):
        pass

    @name.deleter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self):
        pass
```

Then, you need to override them in the child class as shown below:

```py
class Student(Person):
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    
    @classmethod
    def test1(cls): # Overrides abstract class method
        print("Test1")
    
    @staticmethod
    def test2(): # Overrides abstract static method
        print("Test2")
    
    @property
    def name(self): # Overrides abstract getter
        return self._name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name): # Overrides abstract setter
        self._name = name
    
    @name.deleter
    def name(self): # Overrides abstract deleter
        del self._name
```

Then, you can instantiate the child class and call them as shown below:

```py
obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
obj.test1() # Class method
obj.test2() # Static method
print(obj.name) # Getter
obj.name = "Tom" # Setter
print(obj.name) # Getter
del obj.name # Deleter
print(hasattr(obj, "name"))
```

Output:

```
Test1
Test2
John 
Tom  
False
```

You can see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes/74534218#74534218) which explains about **abstract property**.