# How to create abstract properties in python abstract classes?

Tags: python, properties, abstract-class, decorator, abstract-methods

In the following code, I create a base abstract class `Base`. I want all the classes that inherit from `Base` to provide the `name` property, so I made this property an `@abstractmethod`.

Then I created a subclass of `Base`, called `Base_1`, which is meant to supply some functionality, but still remain abstract. There is no `name` property in `Base_1`, but nevertheless python instatinates an object of that class without an error. How does one create abstract properties?

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod

class Base(object):
# class Base(metaclass = ABCMeta): <- Python 3
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    def __init__(self, str_dir_config):
        self.str_dir_config = str_dir_config
    
    @abstractmethod
    def _do_stuff(self, signals):
        pass
    
    @property    
    @abstractmethod
    def name(self):
        """This property will be supplied by the inheriting classes
        individually.
        """
        pass
    

class Base1(Base):
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
    """This class does not provide the name property and should
    raise an error.
    """
    def __init__(self, str_dir_config):
        super(Base1, self).__init__(str_dir_config)
        # super().__init__(str_dir_config) <- Python 3
    
    def _do_stuff(self, signals):
        print "Base_1 does stuff"
        # print("Base_1 does stuff") <- Python 3

class C(Base1):
    @property
    def name(self):
        return "class C"
    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    b1 = Base1("abc")
```

Comment: Gotcha: If you forget to use decorator `@property` in `class C`, `name` will revert to a method.

Answer (score 327, accepted):

Since [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#abc) a bug was fixed meaning the `property()` decorator is now correctly identified as abstract when applied to an abstract method.

Note: Order matters, you have to use `@property` above `@abstractmethod`

**Python 3.3+:** ([python docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty)):

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class C(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        ...
```

**Python 2:** ([python docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty))

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractproperty

class C:
    __metaclass__ = ABCMeta

    @abstractproperty
    def my_abstract_property(self):
        ...
```

Comment: @James How to make it compatible for python 2 and as well?

Comment: @James actually I meant for both but nevermind I posted a answer based on your solution

Comment: i don't think python checks that the implementation actually has @property decorator, it just checks that a method with the name `my_abstract_property` is created.

Comment: @James, does this work with `functools.cached_property`?

Comment: I don't get it. OP is asking about having a property of a base class named `name`, which has to be implemented by all child classes, but the answers here are implementing abstract functions. Even the `abc` docs show only functions being abstract. Isn't there a way to make class properties/variables abstract in a way that child classes have to implement them? I need it to have an `id` variable which all child classes should implement.

Comment: @Nav perhaps you want an [attribute and not a property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374748/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-property-and-attribute)?

Comment: Chaining classmethod descriptors is now deprecated, see https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.11.html

    It can no longer be used to wrap other descriptors such as property. The core design of this feature was flawed and caused a number of downstream problems. To “pass-through” a classmethod, consider using the `__wrapped__` attribute that was added in Python 3.10

Comment: How do I require that the attribute has to be a specific type, e.g. `str`?

Answer (score 58):

Until [Python 3.3](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.3.html#abc), you cannot nest `@abstractmethod` and `@property`.

Use `@abstractproperty` to create abstract properties ([docs](http://docs.python.org/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty)).

```
from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty

class Base(object):
    # ...
    @abstractproperty
    def name(self):
        pass
```

The code now raises the correct exception:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "foo.py", line 36, in 
    b1 = Base_1('abc')  
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Base_1 with abstract methods name
```

Comment: actually this answer is wrong for younger pythons: since 3.3, `@abstractproperty` is deprecated in favor of a combination like OP’s.

Comment: From the 3.3 docs: http://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty

Comment: [@abstractproperty in the Python 2 docs](https://docs.python.org/2/library/abc.html#abc.abstractproperty)

Comment: so until 3.3, just `raise NotImplementedError`

Comment: can we inherit from object and still use the ABC annotations?  Will it work as shown in the example?

Answer (score 10):

Based on James answer above

```
def compatibleabstractproperty(func):

    if sys.version_info > (3, 3):             
        return property(abstractmethod(func))
    else:
        return abstractproperty(func)
```

and use it as a decorator

```
@compatibleabstractproperty
def env(self):
    raise NotImplementedError()
```

Comment: eeesh! what a mess!

Answer (score 8):

For example, you can define the abstract getter, setter and deleter with `@abstractmethod` and `@property`, `@name.setter` or `@name.deleter` in **`Person` abstract class** as shown below. *`@abstractmethod` must be the innermost decorator otherwise error occurs:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Person(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self): # Abstract getter
        pass

    @name.setter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self, name): # Abstract setter
        pass

    @name.deleter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self): # Abstract deleter
        pass
```

Then, you can extend **`Person` abstract class** with **`Student` class**, override the abstract getter, setter and deleter in **`Student` class**, instantiate **`Student` class** and call the getter, setter and deleter as shown below:

```py
class Student(Person):

    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    
    @property
    def name(self): # Overrides abstract getter
        return self._name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name): # Overrides abstract setter
        self._name = name
    
    @name.deleter
    def name(self): # Overrides abstract deleter 
        del self._name

obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
print(obj.name) # Getter
obj.name = "Tom" # Setter
print(obj.name) # Getter
del obj.name # Deleter
print(hasattr(obj, "name"))
```

Output:

```
John
Tom
False
```

Actually, even if you don't override the abstract setter and deleter in **`Student` class** and instantiate **`Student` class** as shown below:

```py
class Student(Person): # Extends "Person" class
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    
    @property
    def name(self): # Overrides only abstract getter
        return self._name

    # @name.setter
    # def name(self, name): # Overrides abstract setter
    #     self._name = name
    
    # @name.deleter
    # def name(self): # Overrides abstract deleter 
    #     del self._name

obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
# ...
```

No error occurs as shown below:

```
John
Tom
False
```

But, if you don't override the abstract getter, setter and deleter in **`Student` class** and instantiate **`Student` class** as shown below:

```py
class Student(Person): # Extends "Person" class
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    
    # @property
    # def name(self): # Overrides only abstract getter
    #     return self._name

    # @name.setter
    # def name(self, name): # Overrides abstract setter
    #     self._name = name
    
    # @name.deleter
    # def name(self): # Overrides abstract deleter 
    #     del self._name

obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
# ...
```

The error below occurs:

> TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class Student with abstract methods name

And, if you don't override the abstract getter in **`Student` class** and instantiate **`Student` class** as shown below:

```py
class Student(Person): # Extends "Person" class
    
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    
    # @property
    # def name(self): # Overrides only abstract getter
    #     return self._name

    @name.setter
    def name(self, name): # Overrides abstract setter
        self._name = name
    
    @name.deleter
    def name(self): # Overrides abstract deleter 
        del self._name

obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
# ...
```

The error below occurs:

> NameError: name 'name' is not defined

And, if `@abstractmethod` is not the innermost decorator as shown below:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Person(ABC):

    @abstractmethod # Not the innermost decorator
    @property
    def name(self): # Abstract getter
        pass

    @name.setter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self, name): # Abstract setter
        pass

    @name.deleter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self): # Abstract deleter
        pass
```

The error below occurs:

> AttributeError: attribute '**isabstractmethod**' of 'property' objects is not writable

Comment: How to annotate this? If I use `--> str` on the property, it does not complain if I make it an int in a lower class.

Answer (score 6):

Using the `@property` decorator in the abstract class (as recommended in the [answer by James](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48710068/13305627)) works if you want the required instance level attributes to use the property decorator as well.

If you don't want to use the property decorator, you can use `super()`. I ended up using something like the `__post_init__()` from dataclasses and it gets the desired functionality for instance level attributes:

```py
import abc
from typing import List

class Abstract(abc.ABC):
    """An ABC with required attributes.

    Attributes:
        attr0
        attr1 
    """

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def __init__(self):
        """Forces you to implement __init__ in 'Concrete'. 
        Make sure to call __post_init__() from inside 'Concrete'."""

    def __post_init__(self):
        self._has_required_attributes()
        # You can also type check here if you want.

    def _has_required_attributes(self):
        req_attrs: List[str] = ['attr0', 'attr1']
        for attr in req_attrs:
            if not hasattr(self, attr):
                raise AttributeError(f"Missing attribute: '{attr}'")

class Concrete(Abstract):

    def __init__(self, attr0, attr1):
        self.attr0 = attr0
        self.attr1 = attr1
        self.attr2 = "some value" # not required
        super().__post_init__() # Enforces the attribute requirement.
```

Answer (score 6):

In [python 3.6+](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0526/#id8), you can also anotate a variable without providing a default. I find this to be a more concise way to make it abstract.

```py
class Base():
    name: str
    
    def print_name(self):
        print(self.name)  # will raise an Attribute error at runtime if `name` isn't defined in subclass

class Base_1(Base):
    name = "base one"
```

it may also be used to force you to initialize the variable in the `__new__` or `__init__` methods

As another example, the following code will fail when you try to initialize the `Base_1` class

```py
    class Base():
        name: str

        def __init__(self):
            self.print_name()

    class Base_1(Base):
        _nemo = "base one"
    
    b = Base_1()
```

`AttributeError: 'Base_1' object has no attribute 'name'`

Comment: Didn't work for me. Python 3.9.6. Perhaps you missed something?

Comment: well, something that might not be clear from my response is that you'll only get the error when you try to access the missing attribute. so you could easily check that in the `__init__` method for example. I'll update to my answer to demonstrate that. (by the way, I tested it with Python 3.8.6)

Comment: Maybe this answer is useful, but it's not what the OP question is asking about. You are defining an attribute, not a property.

Comment: This solution might even be dangerous. If you define it this way, you can’t expect that people actually implement it. And if you want to use it later on it might crash, while the linter thinks that this attribute exists. So it has no advantage defining it in the Base class, only disadvantages.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible solution is to use [metaclasses](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#metaclasses).

A minimal example can look like this:

```
class BaseMetaClass(type):
    def __new__(mcls, class_name, bases, attrs):
        required_attrs = ('foo', 'bar')
        for attr in required_attrs:
            if not attr in attrs:
                raise RunTimeError(f"You need to set {attr} in {class_name}")
        return super().__new__(mcls, class_name, bases, attrs)


class Base(metaclass=BaseMeta):
    foo: str
    bar: int
```

One advantage of this approach is that the check will happen at definition time (not instantiation).

Also, setting class attributes in child classes is a bit easier than declaring properties (as long as they are simple values known in advance) and your final classes will look more concise

Comment: I like this direction, but I want it to automatically require all attributes that `Base` is going to get. Any subclass like `SubclassBase(Base)` should then be forced to have these attributes.