# What's the difference between a Python "property" and "attribute"?

Tags: python, properties, attributes

I am generally confused about the difference between a "property" and an "attribute", and I can't find a great resource to concisely detail the differences.

Answer (score 245, accepted):

Properties are a special kind of attribute.  Basically, when Python encounters the following code:

```
spam = SomeObject()
print(spam.eggs)
```

it looks up `eggs` in `SomeObject`<sup>1</sup>, and then examines `eggs` to see if it has a `__get__`, `__set__`, or `__delete__` method -- if it does, it's a property, and Python will call the `__get__` method (since we were doing lookup) and return whatever that method returns.  If it is not a property, then `eggs` is looked up in `spam`, and whatever is found there will be returned.

More information about [Python's data model and descriptors](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#implementing-descriptors).

---

<sup>1</sup> Many thanks to Robert Seimer for the correction on the lookup sequence.

Comment: It sounds like properties involve additional processing to access the target value...do you know how significant / much slower it is?

Comment: @martineau:  Well, there's one extra function call, but most likely the extra work and time will depend on how much the property is doing (general advice:  do /not/ use properties to hide I/O).

Comment: No, it does not look up `eggs` in `spam`, but in `SomeObject`. (The former will not have an `__get__` method in the general case, property or not.)

Comment: @RobertSiemer: Nope, it goes to `spam` -- that's why caching properties work.  You're thinking of dunder methods like `__getitem__`, `__len__`, etc.

Comment: Nope, it actually goes through the entire MRO of `SomeObject` first. If it finds `eggs` there and it is a data descriptor, it never touches the instance  `spam` at all. Further, the `eggs` of the `spam` instance is never checked for “descriptorness”. It is used as-is if no descriptor is found in the MRO chain, or if that descriptor is a non-data descriptor. (With the latter getting called if the instance has no `eggs`.)

Comment: @RobertSiemer: Right you are!  Answer updated.

Answer (score 103):

With a property you have complete control on its getter, setter and deleter methods, which you don't have (if not using caveats) with an attribute.

```
class A(object):
    _x = 0
    '''A._x is an attribute'''

    @property
    def x(self):
        '''
        A.x is a property
        This is the getter method
        '''
        return self._x

    @x.setter
    def x(self, value):
        """
        This is the setter method
        where I can check it's not assigned a value < 0
        """
        if value < 0:
            raise ValueError("Must be >= 0")
        self._x = value

>>> a = A()
>>> a._x = -1
>>> a.x = -1
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "ex.py", line 15, in <module>
    a.x = -1
  File "ex.py", line 9, in x
    raise ValueError("Must be >= 0")
ValueError: Must be >= 0
```

Comment: This ("complete control") can be done with "non-property" attributes as well though, just without such simple decorators.

Comment: I like that this answer provides a realistic and useful example. I feel that too many answers on this site needlessly explain how things work on the back-end without clarifying how the user should interact with them. If one doesn't understand why/when to use some functionality, there is no point knowing how it operates behind the scenes.

Comment: This answer violate the "Zen of Python - There should be one -- and preferably only one -- obvious way to do it". There are 2 ways to set x value.

Comment: @TinLuu - There is only one way to set the value of x. There is also only one way to set the value of _x. The fact that they are the same thing is an implementation detail. The wise user of this class does not use _x.

Comment: @lit: considering _x, a.x=1 or a._x=1 both change value of _x, isn't that multiple way to change value of _x?

Comment: @TinLuu - I think we are both saying the same thing from opposite ends of the perspective. The user of the class should only see `x`. One way. If the user of the class finds out about _x, they use it at their own risk.

Comment: @TinLuu, considering _x, a.x=-1 or a._x=-1 they behave differently and that's the point in having getters and setters. Otherwise just use attributes.

Answer (score 26):

In general speaking terms a property and an attribute are the same thing. However, there is a property decorator in Python which provides getter/setter access to an attribute (or other data).

```
class MyObject(object):
    # This is a normal attribute
    foo = 1

    @property
    def bar(self):
        return self.foo

    @bar.setter
    def bar(self, value):
        self.foo = value


obj = MyObject()
assert obj.foo == 1
assert obj.bar == obj.foo
obj.bar = 2
assert obj.foo == 2
assert obj.bar == obj.foo
```

Comment: could you please also mention the expected outcome of this code?

Comment: What do you mean? Isn't that at the bottom of the code?

Answer (score 21):

The property allows you to get and set values like you would normal attributes, but underneath there is a method being called translating it into a getter and setter for you.  It's really just a convenience to cut down on the boilerplate of calling getters and setters.

Lets say for example, you had a class that held some x and y coordinates for something you needed.  To set them you might want to do something like:

```
myObj.x = 5
myObj.y = 10
```

That is much easier to look at and think about than writing:

```
myObj.setX(5)
myObj.setY(10)
```

The problem is, what if one day your class changes such that you need to offset your x and y by some value?  Now you would need to go in and change your class definition and all of the code that calls it, which could be really time consuming and error prone.  The property allows you to use the former syntax while giving you the flexibility of change of the latter.

In Python, you can define getters, setters, and delete methods with the property function.  If you just want the read property, there is also a @property decorator you can add above your method.

http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property

Comment: Only answer that made practical sense!

Answer (score 18):

I learnt 2 differences from  [site](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php) of Bernd Klein, in summary:

**1. A property is a more convenient way to achieve data encapsulation**

For example, let's say you have a public attribute `length`. Later on, your project requires you to encapsulate it, i.e. to change it to private and provide a getter and setter => you have to change the the code you wrote before:

```
# Old code
obj1.length = obj1.length + obj2.length
# New code (using private attributes and getter and setter)
obj1.set_length(obj1.get_length() + obj2.get_length()) # => this is ugly
```

If you use `@property` and `@length.setter` => you don't need to change that old code.

**2. A property can encapsulate multiple attributes**

```
class Person:
  def __init__(self, name, physic_health, mental_health):
    self.name = name
    self.__physic_health = physic_health 
    self.__mental_health = mental_health 

  @property
  def condition(self):
    health = self.__physic_health + self.__mental_health
    if(health < 5.0):
      return "I feel bad!"
    elif health < 8.0:
      return "I am ok!"
    else:
      return "Great!"
```

In this example, `__physic_health` and `__mental_health` are private and cannot be accessed directly from outside.

Answer (score 10):

There is also one not obvious difference that i use to cache or refresh data , often we have a function connected to class attribute. For instance i need to read file once and keep content assigned to the attribute so the value is cached:

```
class Misc():
        def __init__(self):
            self.test = self.test_func()

        def test_func(self):
            print 'func running'
            return 'func value'

cl = Misc()
print cl.test
print cl.test
```

Output:

```
func running
func value
func value
```

We accessed the attribute twice but our function was fired only once. Changing the above example to use property will cause attribute's value refresh each time you access it:

```
class Misc():

    @property
    def test(self):
        print 'func running'
        return 'func value'

cl = Misc()
print cl.test
print cl.test
```

Output:

```
func running
func value
func running
func value
```

Answer (score 10):

I like to think that, if you want to set a restriction for an attribute, use a property.

Although all attributes are public, generally programmers differentiate public and private attributes with an underscore(`_`). Consider the following class,

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self.b = 3    # To show public
        self._c = 4   # To show private
```

Here, `b` attribute is intended to be accessed from outside class A. But, readers of this class might wonder, can `b` attribute be set from outside class `A`?

If we intend to not set `b` from outside, we can show this intention with `@property`.

```py
class A:
    def __init__(self):
        self._c = 4   # To show private
   
    @property
    def b(self):
        return 3
```

Now, `b` can't be set.

```py
a = A()
print(a.b)   # prints 3
a.b = 7      # Raises AttributeError
```

Or, if you wish to set only certain values,

```py
class A:
    @property 
    def b(self):
        return self._b
    
    @b.setter
    def b(self, val):
        if val < 0:
            raise ValueError("b can't be negative")
        self._b = val

a = A()
a.b = 6     # OK
a.b = -5    # Raises ValueError
```

Answer (score 0):

Attribute is actually at the object.

Property is propagated by proxy. (Its value may be calculated on the fly.)

---

See also

- https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#getattr : a builtin function
- https://docs.python.org/dev/library/functions.html#property : a builtin [decorator](https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-decorator)
- https://docs.python.org/dev/glossary.html#term-attribute

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).