# Python - Automatically update base class attribute (alias) in inherited class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm sure this is something trivial, but I can't seem to find any insight from the Python (3) docs.

Given the following code, how can I ensure that the `t` class attribute in the base class is updated in the inherited class.

```
class DbBase:
    table = None
    t = table

class Articles(DbBase):
    table = Table(....)
```

I'd now like to be able to refer to `Article.table` as `Article.t` as well.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Make `t` a `property`:

```
class DbBase:
    table = None
    @property
    def t(self):
        return self.table

class Articles(DbBase):
    table = {} # for demo purposes

A = Articles()
A.t # returns {}
```

Comment: Probably want a setter on `t` too.

Comment: https://docs.python.org/3.4/library/functions.html#property -- Thanks! Didn't realize that @property was applicable to class attributes. Related SO question with more insights: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374748/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-property-and-attribute