# 'MyClass' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python

I have a class like this one:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, id, a, b, c):
        self.myList     = []
        self.id         = id
        self.a          = a
        self.b          = b
        self.c          = c

    def addData(self, data):
        self.myList.append(data)
```

In my main code, I create a list of MyClass instances called `myClassList`. In a line I have to check if an item with a given `id` already exists. I do it in this way:

```
id = 'foo' # in real code is set dynamically 
recent_item = next( (item for item in myClassList if item['id'] == id), None )
```

The second line in that code gives this error:

> 'MyClass' object has no attribute `'__getitem__'`

How can I fix?

Comment: You need to add a `__getitem__`

Comment: ...you could implement `__getitem__`! Alternatively, use `item.id` instead of `item['id']`. Note also that you're assigning `self.id = a`, which is likely not what you intended, and aren't compliant with [the style guide](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/).

Answer (score 32, accepted):

`item` is not a dictionary but a class so it has different syntax for accessing members. Access `id` this way instead:

```
item.id
```

Comment: ah python ‍♂️just had the opposite issue with a dict

Answer (score 20):

If you actually wanted to be able to access your attributes using `inst["attr"]` and to explain your error, you would need to add a `__getitem__` to you class:

```
class MyClass(object):
    def __init__(self, id, a, b, c):
        self.myList     = []
        self.id         = id
        self.a          = a
        self.b          = b
        self.c          = c

    def addData(self, data):
        self.myList.append(data)

    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return getattr(self, item)
```

Comment: I think this should be the accepted answer, provides a work around too.

Answer (score 4):

As others have noted, you can simply use

```
item.id
```

However, sometimes you do need to use this syntax if you are accessing a field dynamically:

```
item[dynamicField]
```

In that case, you can use the __getitem__() syntax as Anand suggested, however it is safer to use python's wrapper for __getitem__:

```
getattr(item, dynamicField)
```

Answer (score 1):

Like the error suggests, you can only use subscript on class instances, if the class defines a `__getitem__()` instance method.

As `id` is an attribute of the instance, you should use - `item.id` instead of `item['id']` .

Example -

```
recent_item = next( (item for item in myClassList if item.id == id), None )
```

Answer (score 1):

`id` is an attribute of MyClass instance, you have to access it as `item.id`

```
recent_item = next( (item for item in myClassList if item.id == id), None )
```

Comment: It's an *attribute*, a *property* is something different.

Comment: Sorry to beat a dead bush, but I think it would be correct to call it a property in this case? https://stackoverflow.com/a/7374831/6743506