# Python: modifying property value

Tags: python, class, properties

I have the following code that uses two simple properties:

```
class Text(object):

    @property
    def color(self):
        return 'blue'

    @property
    def length(self):
        return 22

t = Text()
print t.color
```

When I run this, it obviously returns `blue`. But how can I update the value of color on the fly later in the code? I.e. when I try to do:

```
t = Text()
print t.color
t.color = 'red'
print t.color
```

It fails with a `can't set attribute` error. Is there a way to modify the value of a property?

**EDIT:**

If the above code is rewritten to use setters as in williamtroup's answer, what is the advantage of simply shortening it to:

```
class Text(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self.color = self.add_color()
        self.length = self.add_length()

    def add_color(self):
        return 'blue'

    def add_length(self):
        return 22
```

Comment: Answering your edit; Not Pythonic and a bad habit.

Comment: @EddB How's it not Pythonic?

Comment: Either way, the question was answered. Its up to you as to decide which is the best way to implement your class.

Comment: Read [this](http://www.python-course.eu/python3_properties.php)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need a setter for the property and a class variable to store the data.

With your example:

```
class Text(object):

    def __init__(self):
        self._color = "blue"
        self._length = 12

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self._color

    @color.setter
    def color(self, value):
        self._color = value

    @property
    def length(self):
        return self._length

    @length.setter
    def length(self, value):
        self._length = value
```

Comment: If rewritten using setters, what's the advantage over simply using attributes? See my edit to the question.

Comment: Refer to this question:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7374748/whats-the-difference-between-a-python-property-and-attribute.  That should tell you everything you need.

Comment: Right, I understand the difference, but why would you use one over the other? Also, if I want a default value computed based on some logic, I would need three functions: two properties, getter and setter, and one more function to fill `self._color` with a value based on that logic. That's three functions over just one when using attributes.

Comment: The setter is the function to fill `self._color` yet.

Comment: Even though __init__() is technically a function, its actually the constructor for the class.  You can do it either way, I prefer the "setter" approach as it allows me to practice good encapsulation rules (yes, even in python).

Comment: Sorry, I guess I'm not asking this clearly. I'm wondering how to modify the code to basically have two setters. One setter that fills in `self._color` with some color, say a random one from a given list, and another setter that allows me to directly set the color to a chosen value via `t.color = 'red'`.

Comment: That can be done from outside the class instance, as you would get the value sorted and then set it using the color() property.