# python class: why do I get maximum recursion when trying to set an attribue with @property decorator?

Tags: python, class, attributes, setter

I am learning how to create classes in python where when modifying attribute 1 will change attribute 2.
For instance a circle with an attribue radius.

```
class Circle():
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self._radius = radius
        
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius

    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, value):
        self.radius = value
    
    @property
    def area(self):
        return 3.14*self.radius*self.radius
```

And this happens:

```
c = Circle(3)
c.area
```

All fine. but now:

```
c.radius = 56
print(c.area)
```

gives:

```
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

The question is why?
What is the way to force recalculation of other attributes when one is changed?

I have consulted several answers:
[Python: modifying property value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36029389/python-modifying-property-value)
[How do you change the value of one attribute by changing the value of another? (dependent attributes)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27308560/how-do-you-change-the-value-of-one-attribute-by-changing-the-value-of-another)

EDIT:
According to some answers (see bellow) I am in an infinite loop. So I delete the part of the setter. I remain with:

```
class Circle():
    def __init__(self,radius):
        self._radius = radius
        
    @property
    def radius(self):
        return self._radius
    
    @property
    def area(self):
        return 3.14*self.radius*self.radius
```

What happens then is:

```
c = Circle(3)
c.radius = 30
```

error: AttributeError: can't set attribute

Comment: You've told Python that you set `radius` by setting `radius`, which you do by setting `radius`, which you do by setting `radius`, which you do by setting `radius`...

Comment: Because the code for setting `self.radius` invokes the code for setting `self.radius`. You probably meant `self._radius = value`.

Comment: thanks for the answers. I tried to solve it by deleting the setter, and it did not work I got an error as seen in the EDIT part of the question.

Comment: Why did you delete the setter? The solution is to use `self._radius = value` in the setter.

Answer (score 0):

## After the comments posted here this is the answer with exploratory explanation:

```
class Circle():
    def __init__(self, _radius, color):
        print('init run')
        self._radius = _radius
        self.color = color
        
    @property
    def radius(self):
        print('property radius run')
        return self._radius
    
    @radius.setter
    def radius(self, value):
        print('setter radius run')
        self._radius = value
    
    @property
    def area(self):
        print('property AREA run')
        return 3.14*self.radius*self.radius
```

I added print statements because if you want to find out what really happens I recommend you to run this code in separate cells in a notebook:

```
c= Circle(3,'azul') # here only __init__ runs
print(c.radius) # here property radius run

print(c.area)
```

This is the interesting part. When printing c.area things happen. Before running the code think about what do you think it would happenI was surprised but relieved because I understood now the functioning.
This is what happens: property AREA run, property radius run, property radius run.
My lessons learnt: Accessing the radius property is done via the method. This WAS NOT AT ALL OBVIOUS FOR ME.

Now try to change the radius

```
c.radius = 56 # setter method runs

print(c.area)   # the same ass before.
```