# How to write to an abstract property in Python 3.4+

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, abstract-class

In Python 3.6, Let's say I have an abstract class `MyAbstractClass`

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class MyAbstractClass(ABC):

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def myProperty(self):
        pass
```

and a class `MyInstantiatableClass` inherit from it. So how do I write to the property `myProperty` on instantiation of an object from this class? I'd like to be able to both set and get `myProperty`. Below doesn't work.

```
from MyAbstractClass import MyAbstractClass

class MyInstantiatableClass(MyAbstractClass):
    def __init__(self, desiredValueOfMyProperty):
        ????

    @myProperty.setter
    def myProperty(self, desiredValueOfMyProperty): # value coming from __init__
        self._myProperty = desiredValueOfMyProperty
```

And a main function, say,

```
from MyInstantiatableClass import MyInstantiatableClass

def main():
    MyInstantiatableClass(3) # 3 is the desiredValueOfMyProperty for this instantiation
    MyInstantiatableClass(5) # 5 is the desiredValueOfMyProperty for this instantiation
```

Comment: Are you implementing _only_ the setter, without a getter?

Comment: I'd like to be able to both set and get `myProperty` at `MyInstantiatableClass`.

Comment: Define the property the same way you would normally.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It seems there's a discrepancy here; using `@property` along with `@abstractmethod` doesn't seem to enforce classes that inherit from your abc to need to define both `setter` and `getter`. Using this:

```
@property
@abstractmethod
def myProperty(self):
    pass

@myProperty.setter
@abstractmethod
def myProperty(self):
    pass
```

and then providing an implementation only for the `getter` in the class works and allows for instantiation:

```
@property
def myProperty(self):
    return self._myProperty
```

This is due to the fact that only one name (`myProperty`) appears in the namespace of the ABC, when you override in the base class, you only need to define this one name.

There's a way around that enforces it. You can create separate abstract methods and pass them on to `property` directly:

```
class MyAbstractClass(ABC):

    @abstractmethod
    def getProperty(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def setProperty(self, val):
        pass

    myAbstractProperty = property(getProperty, setProperty)
```

Providing an implementation for this abc now requires both `getter` and `setter` to have an implementation (both names that have been listed as `abstractmethod`s in `MyAbstractClass` namespace need to have an implementation):

```
class MyInstantiatableClass(MyAbstractClass):

    def getProperty(self):
        return self._Property

    def setProperty(self, val):
        self._Property = val
    myAbstractProperty = property(getProperty, setProperty)
```

Implementing them is exactly the same as any old property. There's no difference there.

Comment: The abstract property doesn't need to use `.setter`, and specifying `.setter` on the abstract property won't force the concrete implementation to have a setter or anything like that.

Comment: @user2357112 I wasn't expecting that, it's true. You can apparently force the implementation to define both by passing `abstractmethods` directly to `property`.

Answer (score 0):

For example, you can define the abstract getter, setter and deleter in **`Person` abstract class**, override them in **`Student` class** which extends **`Person` abstract class** as shown below. *`@abstractmethod` must be the innermost decorator otherwise error occurs:

```py
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class Person(ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self): # Abstract getter
        pass

    @name.setter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self, name): # Abstract setter
        pass

    @name.deleter
    @abstractmethod # The innermost decorator
    def name(self): # Abstract deleter
        pass

class Student(Person):
    def __init__(self, name):
        self._name = name
    
    @property
    def name(self): # Overrides abstract getter
        return self._name
    
    @name.setter
    def name(self, name): # Overrides abstract setter
        self._name = name
    
    @name.deleter
    def name(self): # Overrides abstract deleter 
        del self._name
```

Then, you can instantiate **`Student` class** and call the getter, setter and deleter as shown below:

```py
obj = Student("John") # Instantiates "Student" class
print(obj.name) # Getter
obj.name = "Tom" # Setter
print(obj.name) # Getter
del obj.name # Deleter
print(hasattr(obj, "name"))
```

Output:

```
John
Tom
False
```

You can see [**my answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes/74534218#74534218) which explains more about **abstract property**.