# What is the way of enforcing explicit initialization of parent class by an implementer?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Consider the following sample snippet

```
import abc


class BASE(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, name):
        assert name is not None, "Name must be provided."
        self.num = 3

    @abc.abstractmethod
    def compute(self):
        pass


class CHILD(BASE):
    def __init__(name):
         '''
         '''


    def compute(self):
        return self.num + 34
```

On execution it gives the following sensible error :

> AttributeError: 'CHILD' object has no attribute 'num'

In the present situation BASE is not being initialized because if we add a print function to it as below, it does not print absolutely anything.

```
class BASE(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    def __init__(self, name):
        print(name)
        assert name is not None, "Name must be provided."
        self.num = 3
```

**Can we do anything in this class design to make sure that an implementor subclassing from `BASE` must explicitly call the initializer of the `BASE` ?**

Comment: Would it suffice to only assure that `self.num` is defined? If so, the `@abstractproperty` decorator can do the trick... or stacking `@abstractmethod` and `@property` (Python 3.3+).

More details: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes

Comment: . umm. In this case yes, it would suffice. But I was thinking about more complicated and larger-scale projects, where for example a parent class might work to initialize some database or do some authentication or do some other non-trivial work. In such a case an enforced explicit initialization would matter (or so I think).

Comment: I see... and this must happen when an instance of a child class is instantiated? That is, not when the child class itself is created?

Comment: I think that if you speculate by design that it is up to the subclass writer to ensure they call super.

Comment: +1 on comment by @kyle - in Python it is generally assumed that we are all consenting adults. Which means that if you properly document your base class and how it should be subclassed (including calling its `__init__()` method), it is not unreasonable to assume that an adult person using it will read the docs and honor its expectations.

Comment: @plamut I used "instantiated" to refer to `__init__` because strictly speaking `__init__` is not a constructor.

@kyle Maybe you are right. I am not an expert in design patterns. I just wanted to understand that how in real world problems, designs are made to ensure that such mistakes do not happen.

Answer (score 0):

> Can we do anything in this class design to make sure that an
>   implementor subclassing from BASE must explicitly call the initializer
>   of the BASE ?

I guess you can do something like this:

```
class BASE(metaclass=abc.ABCMeta):
    '''
    when subclassing this class, ensure you explicitly 
    call super().__init__() for this parent class
    '''
    def __init__(self, name):
        assert name is not None, "Name must be provided."
        self.num = 3
```

From comments secion:

> I just wanted to understand that how in real world problems, designs
>   are made to ensure that such mistakes do not happen

I have done many sub-classes where I did not explicitly call the `super().__init__()` of the parent class. So I am not sure if you can say that all sub-classes must call the parent class `__init__` to avoid "mistakes" (as you call it). It is up to the creator of the parent class to document properly how to sub-class, and then it is still up to the creator of the sub-class to either do it or not. Not something you can "enforce"