# force implementing specific attributes in subclass python

Tags: python, inheritance, interface

I'm have a parent class, and I would like to "force" everyone that will inherit from it to implement some specific class attributes.

I don't have this problem with methods, since I have created a dummy method that raises `NotImplementedError`, which makes it very clear.

As for class attributes- I do not want to create them in the parent class and set them to None since that doesn't force the developer to implement them in the child class.

A little code to demonstrate the current situation:

```
class Pet(object):
    name = None

    def make_noise(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Needs to implement in subclass")

    def print_my_name(self):
        print(self.name)

class Dog(Pet):
    # how to force declairing "name" attribute for subclasses?

    def make_noise(self):
        print("Whof Whof")
```

In this example, developer 1 created Pet class and wanted other developers to implement subclass with a "name" attribute.
Developer2 implemented a subclass, but didn't know he needs implement the "name" attribute.

Is it possible to create such restrictions in python?

Comment: See https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html , scroll down to the docs for abstractmethod.

Comment: I feel like name should related to object, if so, you can do .__init__(name)... And if you want some doc to describe dog as a type, you can use .__doc__/.__str__/.__repr__ .etc

Comment: @ShengZhuang, yeah I tend to agree, i guess i didn't do it that way because in my case the leaf class (dog) is not a direct subclass of the parent (pet), so i didn't want to "drag" that variable in the init of all the other parents, but actually why not?

Answer (score 1):

You can try by using [ABCMeta](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABCMeta) metaclass or [ABC](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.ABC).
After that you can use the [@abstractmethod](https://docs.python.org/3/library/abc.html#abc.abstractmethod) of an [@property](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#property).
eg:

```
from abc import ABC

class Pet(ABC):
    @abstractmethod
    @property
    def name(self):
        pass

    @abstractmethod
    def make_noise(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Needs to implement in subclass")

    def print_my_name(self):
        print(self.name)
```

With this you can add a setter as well with `@name.setter`.

Comment: Forgot ":" on method declaration

Comment: This does not work in Python 3.11. Error is `AttributeError: attribute '__isabstractmethod__' of 'property' objects is not writable`

Comment: `Note: Order matters, you have to use @property above @abstractmethod` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes

Answer (score 0):

I've had this question for a while as well. After reading the comment by @Sheng Zhuang I think his suggestion is the way to go.

If `name` is an attribute used by `Pet`, and indeed must be defined for all `Pet`s but may be different between different types of `Pet`s then the proper way to handle this is with a parameter input to `Pet`'s `__init__` function.

```
class Pet(object):
    def __init__(self, pet_type, name):
        self.pet_type = pet_type
        self.name = name

    def make_noise(self):
        raise NotImplementedError("Needs to implement in subclass")

    def print_my_pet_type(self):
        print(self.pet_type)

    def print_my_name(self):
        print(self.name)

class Dog(Pet):
    def __init__(self, name):
        super().__init__(pet_type='dog', name=name)

    def make_noise(self):
        print("Whof Whof")
```

I've included `pet_type` and `name` for comparison.

`pet_type` is something that the developer who writes `Dog` can/should pass into `Pet.__init__`.

`name` is something that is still exposed to the end user of `Dog` class and they can pass in whatever they like.

edit: I think the semantic downside to this is that `pet_type` is not really an instance attribute the way `name` is. The intention is that all `Dog`s will have the same `pet_type`, so it would be a little more semantically consistent if `Pet` could somehow enforce that all subclasses must define `SubPet.pet_type =` as a class attribute, but given that there's no clean way to do that, I think instance attributes passed through `super()` are the way to go.

Answer (score -1):

use can use python's `Abstract Base Class` / `ABS` or `Method Overriding` whichever is feasible for you as per your requirements.

Comment: that looks really cool! in the ABS and method overriding the focus is on the methods and not attributes.
I guess if I would use one of this ways i would have to implement a set function