# How to declare instance variables in abstract class?

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, inheritance, abstract-class

```
class ILinkedListElem:
    @property
    def value(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    def next(self):
        raise NotImplementedError


class ListElem(ILinkedListElem):
    def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
        self.value = value
        self.next = next_node
```

I wanna something like this. This abstract variables definition works for class vars, but not for instance

I want to all instances of ILinkedListElem subclass must has "value" and "next" attributes

Comment: This has nothing to do with abstract classes. You didn't define a setter for either property. Neither `value` nor `next` is an instance attribute.

Comment: Does this have what you're looking for? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes

Comment: @Vin, No, this question about class variables, but I need to instances variables

Comment: @chepner Yes, I didnt. This example of class var declaration. I wanna something like this, but for class instance vars

Comment: So all you want to do is ensure that a subclass of `ILinkedListElem` defines `value` and `next` attributes? Just set them in an inherited `__init__` method.

Comment: @chepner yes, but ```__init__``` may be overriden in subclass without calling ```super().__init__()```. I was want to require all of this vars in instances. My problem already solved. Thanks

Comment: A subclass can override anything it wants in any way. You're leaving it to the user to define `__init__` in the first place, and the user can also override the two properties. At some point, you just have to trust that the user isn't going to obviously shoot themselves in the foot, because there's nothing you can do to stop it.

Comment: @chepner Thanks, I'll take that into consideration. With properties, this atleast requires two properties with same names inside subclass, but ```__init__``` will not requires anything, I think

Comment: Nothing requires a subclass to define *anything*. You can use the inherited ones (you'll get a `NotImplemented` error if you try to use them, sure, but subclassing will still work). Even if the subclass does override them, nothing says they have to assign properties (even if you use the `abc` module; it doesn't enforce overriding an abstract property with another property, only with *something*) to those names.

Comment: Maybe you are using a type checker of some kind that won't allow the type of the inherited names to be changed, but that's not indicated in the question. (Honestly, it looks more like you are writing Java with a Pythonic accent than actual Python.)

Comment: @chepner Oh, I hadn't thought of that. Thanks for help, I will try to make my python code more pythonic

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to force/require all instances of any subclass of `ILinkedListElem` to have the attributes "`value`" and "`nxt`", the following standard implementation with `abstractmethod` seems to do what you're after:

```
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class ILinkedListElem (ABC):
    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def value(self):
        raise NotImplementedError

    @property
    @abstractmethod
    def nxt(self):
        raise NotImplementedError
```

This is the abstract class, from which we create a compliant subclass:

```
class ListElem_good (ILinkedListElem):
    
    def __init__(self, value, next_node=None):
        self._value = value
        self._nxt = next_node
        
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
    
    @property
    def nxt(self):
        return self._nxt
```

We create an instance of this compliant subclass and test it:

```
x = ListElem_good('foo', 'bar')
print (x.value)
print (x.nxt)

#result:
    # foo
    # bar
```

If we create a non-compliant subclass that omits an implementation of `nxt`, like so:

```
class ListElem_bad (ILinkedListElem):
    
    def __init__(self, value):
        self._value = value
        
        
    @property
    def value(self):
        return self._value
```

when we try to create an instance of this non-compliant subclass:

```
y = ListElem_bad('foo')
print (y.value)
```

it fails:

```
    y = ListElem_bad('foo')

TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ListElem_bad with abstract methods nxt
```

This relies on essentially the same solution offered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes), which you suggested in a comment-exchange does not meet your requirements. But when applied to your specific use-case above, it appears to precisely address the issue you've raised - or have I misunderstood?

Comment: Thank you, this is actually what I need, I couldn't think of _value in __init__ and value property instead of just value in __init__