# Subclassing model classes and overriding base methods

Tags: django-models, abstract-class, subclass

I would like to have a Django model 'Owners' with subclasses 'Industry' and 'Household' in such a way that I can iterate over the base class 'Owners' to perform an action which is overridden in each subclass.

My code would be something like this:

""
class Owner(models.Model):
def dothis(self):
print ('base class dothis was called' )

```
class Industry(Owner):
    size=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def dothis(self):
        print(f'Industry dothis says {size}')

class Household(Owner):
    population=models.IntegerField(default=1)
    def dothis(self):
        print (f'Household dothis says  {population}')

def do():
    industry=Industry(size=1)
    industry.save()
    household=Household(population=2)
    household.save()
    for owner in Owner.objects.all():
        owner.dothis()
```

""
This code always invokes the 'dothis()' method of the base class

I guess this should be done by making Owner an abstract class

Since I haven't yet delved into the intricacies of creating abstract classes I'm hopin there is either
(1) a standard way to make 'Owner' an abstract class
(2) a workaround

When I try to create Owner as an abstract class, Django says it is non-iterable. If I try to inherit both from ABCMeta or ABC and from 'models.Model' I get the apparently Infamous message
""
metaclass conflict: the metaclass of a derived class must be a (non-strict) subclass of the metaclasses of all its bases
""
I've looked at this thread

[How to create abstract properties in python abstract classes?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes)

but it's a bit above me at my present knowledge level.

Pointers to other threads, or solutions, would be appreciated.

Comment: Django indeed does not by default check all tables of subclasses, for performance reasons. `django-polymorphic` can do that (https://django-polymorphic.readthedocs.io/en/stable/), but usually inheritance in relational databases is quite "ugly" and inefficient.

Comment: Thanks for this and for the answer. At this stage of development my main aim is DRY code, and so I'd like to put most of the code for ""dothis"" in the base class. Maybe there is another way to achieve that. Of course, I could do without inheritance altogether but it seems a shame because (I feel) it would make the code more comprehensible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This code always invokes the `dothis()` method of the base class

Yes, Django's `Owner.objects.all()` will query the table for the `Owner` table only, and produce `Owner` objects, even if these object originate out of a subclass of `Owner`, so the database-to-objects functionality is not *bijective*.

You can do this with [**`django-polymorphic`** <sup>[pypi]</sup>](https://pypi.org/project/django-polymorphic/), which will look for all model subclasses, and then produce `LEFT OUTER JOIN`s for each table that is a subclass.

But as you probably can guess, this will result in some nice queries, and actually shows a more fundamental problem: inheritance and relational databases often don't work out very well. The modeling of polymorphism in the database is also not very "clean": for example it would strictly speaking be possible for to represent the same object as both `Industry` and `Household` in the database, and there is no way to prevent that the data in the database thus maps to an "invalid" inheritance pattern.

It thus might not be ideal to use inheritance at all.