Force subclass to implement a class property in Python
I want to force all subclasses of a class to implement a property. As I understand it, I have to use abc methods for this use case. I tried the following:
from abc import ABC, abstractmethod

class BaseClass(ABC):
    @property
    @classmethod
    @abstractmethod
    def required_property(cls):
        """This property must be implemented by subclasses."""
        pass

class MySubClass(BaseClass):
    required_property = "Implemented"

class AnotherSubClass(BaseClass):
    pass


if __name__ == "__main__":
    print(MySubClass.required_property)
    print(AnotherSubClass.required_property)

However,

the code executes without errors
mypy complains: property_mypy.py:4:6: error: Only instance methods can be decorated with @property  [misc],
class properties are deprecated in Python 3.11 and will not be supported in Python 3.13 Pylance.

What is the pythonic way to do this?

I don't think you can, if you mean it to be a class attribute: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5960337/how-to-create-abstract-properties-in-python-abstract-classes before, the workaround was basically this, but it isn't going to work anymore

So, I think the most practical solution is just live with it being a regular classmethod
