# abc.abstractclassmethod: Why is __isabstractmethod__ set on callable?

Tags: python-2.7, python-3.x, class-method, abstract-methods

The implementation of abstractclassmethod abc.py in Python 3.4 looks like this:

```
class abstractclassmethod(classmethod):

    __isabstractmethod__ = True

    def __init__(self, callable):
        callable.__isabstractmethod__ = True
        super().__init__(callable)
```

The answer for [Python 2.7 Combine abc.abstractmethod and classmethod](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217878) is based on this implementation.

Why is it necessary to set __isabstractmethod__ on the callable? Wouldn't it be enough to set the class variable __isabstractmethod__ of class abstractclassmethod? Which use case would not work, if the whole __init__() definition would be removed (like in abstractproperty)?