# TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type during multiple inheritance in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x, oop, multiple-inheritance, super

I'm trying to implement a poor prototype of Google using classes in Python. For now, I have methods for Google Translate and Google Drive. For that case, I have the following abstract classes:

```
class AbsTranslator(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def translate(text: str, goal_language: str) -> Optional[str]:
    pass

class AbsDrive(ABC):
  @abstractmethod
  def save_to_drive(text: str) -> None:
    pass
```

The first one is for Google Translate and the second one for Drive.

This is my code for GoogleTranslator and GoogleDrive:

```
class GoogleTranslator(AbsTranslator):
  @staticmethod
  def translate(text: str, goal_language: str) -> Optional[str]:
    return 'translatedText'

class GoogleDrive(AbsDrive):
  @staticmethod
  def save_to_drive(text: str) -> None:
    print('saving to drive...')
```

At the end, I create a class Google and inherit from these two classes

```
class Google(GoogleTranslator, GoogleDrive):
  
  @staticmethod
  def translate(text: str, goal_language: str = "EN") -> Optional[str]:
    return super().translate(text, goal_language)

  @staticmethod
  def save_to_drive(text: str) -> str:
    return super().save_to_drive(text)
```

If I instantiate an object from Google and call `save_to_drive` (or `translate`) like

```
instance: Google = Google()
instance.save_to_drive('drive')
```

I get the error

> TypeError: super(type, obj): obj must be an instance or subtype of type

I did a small research and it seems that `super()` doesn't know where to check correctly so it throws this error but I want to keep my design as it is now and wonder if it's there a way to fix this behavior? Is there a way to keep it this way or instead of `super()`, I should use `GoogleTranslator.translate()` and `GoogleDrive.save_to_drive()`? I did it this way because I want to have one `Google` class that has all of the features in it but the features to be coded in separated classes.

Comment: You could use GoogleTranslator.translate() and GoogleDrive.save_to_drive(). Or you could make them @classmethod. The builtin super expects something to work with, but this is a static method, so there's no self or cls argument. It's basically equivalent to a free function that you've put in the scope of the class -- to use non-python terms. If you're expecting a hierarchy, you might need cls, from classmethod.

Comment: but abstractmethod references "self" in the documentation, so there might be something else here. That's why I haven't posted as an answer. But that might not be a problem according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11217878/python-2-7-combine-abc-abstractmethod-and-classmethod