# In Python, how to enforce an abstract method to be static on the child class?

Tags: python, abstract-class, static-methods, abc

This is the setup I want:
A should be an abstract base class with a static & abstract method f(). B should inherit from A. Requirements:
1. You should not be able to instantiate A
2. You should not be able to instantiate B, unless it implements a static f()

Taking inspiration from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474395/staticmethod-and-abc-abstractmethod-will-it-blend) question, I've tried a couple of approaches. With these definitions:

```
class abstractstatic(staticmethod):
    __slots__ = ()
    def __init__(self, function):
        super(abstractstatic, self).__init__(function)
        function.__isabstractmethod__ = True
    __isabstractmethod__ = True

class A:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @abstractstatic
    def f():
        pass

class B(A):
    def f(self):
        print 'f'

class A2:
    __metaclass__ = abc.ABCMeta
    @staticmethod
    @abc.abstractmethod
    def f():
        pass

class B2(A2):
    def f(self):
        print 'f'
```

Here A2 and B2 are defined using usual Python conventions and A & B are defined using the way suggested in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4474395/staticmethod-and-abc-abstractmethod-will-it-blend) answer. Following are some operations I tried and the results that were undesired.

With classes A/B:

```
>>> B().f()
f
#This should have thrown, since B doesn't implement a static f()
```

With classes A2/B2:

```
>>> A2()
<__main__.A2 object at 0x105beea90>
#This should have thrown since A2 should be an uninstantiable abstract class

>>> B2().f()
f
#This should have thrown, since B2 doesn't implement a static f()
```

Since neither of these approaches give me the output I want, how do I achieve what I want?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can't do what you want with just `ABCMeta`. ABC enforcement doesn't do *any* type checking, only the presence of *an attribute* with the correct name is enforced.

Take for example:

```
>>> from abc import ABCMeta, abstractmethod, abstractproperty
>>> class Abstract(object):
...     __metaclass__ = ABCMeta
...     @abstractmethod
...     def foo(self): pass
...     @abstractproperty
...     def bar(self): pass
... 
>>> class Concrete(Abstract):
...     foo = 'bar'
...     bar = 'baz'
... 
>>> Concrete()
<__main__.Concrete object at 0x104b4df90>
```

I was able to construct `Concrete()` even though both `foo` and `bar` are simple attributes.

The `ABCMeta` metaclass only tracks how many objects are left with the `__isabstractmethod__` attribute being true; when creating a class from the metaclass (`ABCMeta.__new__` is called) the `cls.__abstractmethods__` attribute is then set to a `frozenset` object with all the names that are still abstract.

`type.__new__` then tests for that `frozenset` and throws a `TypeError` if you try to create an instance.

You'd have to produce your *own* `__new__` method here; subclass `ABCMeta` and add type checking in a new `__new__` method. That method should look for `__abstractmethods__` sets on the base classes, find the corresponding objects with the `__isabstractmethod__` attribute in the MRO, then does typechecking on the current class attributes.

This'd mean that you'd throw the exception when defining the *class*, not an instance, however. For that to work you'd add a `__call__` method to your `ABCMeta` subclass and have that throw the exception based on information gathered by your own `__new__` method about what types were wrong; a similar two-stage process as what `ABCMeta` and `type.__new__` do at the moment. Alternatively, update the `__abstractmethods__` set on the class to add any names that were implemented but with the wrong type and leave it to `type.__new__` to throw the exception.

The following implementation takes that last tack; add names back to `__abstractmethods__` if the implemented type doesn't match (using a mapping):

```
from types import FunctionType

class ABCMetaTypeCheck(ABCMeta):
    _typemap = {  # map abstract type to expected implementation type
        abstractproperty: property,
        abstractstatic: staticmethod,
        # abstractmethods return function objects
        FunctionType: FunctionType,
    }
    def __new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace):
        cls = super(ABCMetaTypeCheck, mcls).__new__(mcls, name, bases, namespace)
        wrong_type = set()
        seen = set()
        abstractmethods = cls.__abstractmethods__
        for base in bases:
            for name in getattr(base, "__abstractmethods__", set()):
                if name in seen or name in abstractmethods:
                    continue  # still abstract or later overridden
                value = base.__dict__.get(name)  # bypass descriptors
                if getattr(value, "__isabstractmethod__", False):
                    seen.add(name)
                    expected = mcls._typemap[type(value)]
                    if not isinstance(namespace[name], expected):
                        wrong_type.add(name)
        if wrong_type:
            cls.__abstractmethods__ = abstractmethods | frozenset(wrong_type)
        return cls
```

With this metaclass you get your expected output:

```
>>> class Abstract(object):
...     __metaclass__ = ABCMetaTypeCheck
...     @abstractmethod
...     def foo(self): pass
...     @abstractproperty
...     def bar(self): pass
...     @abstractstatic
...     def baz(): pass
... 
>>> class ConcreteWrong(Abstract):
...     foo = 'bar'
...     bar = 'baz'
...     baz = 'spam'
... 
>>> ConcreteWrong()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: Can't instantiate abstract class ConcreteWrong with abstract methods bar, baz, foo
>>> 
>>> class ConcreteCorrect(Abstract):
...     def foo(self): return 'bar'
...     @property
...     def bar(self): return 'baz'
...     @staticmethod
...     def baz(): return  'spam'
... 
>>> ConcreteCorrect()
<__main__.ConcreteCorrect object at 0x104ce1d10>
```